# Let the UIAccessibilityPostNotification complete in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uialertview

I want to announce a message through `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` in a `UIAlertView`. My problem is that the alert view closes and the message abruptly stops (at least that is my analysis), barely two words get spoken. Is there any way to let the notification complete? My code is as follows:

```
//Function which calls UIAlertView
-(IBAction)foo:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView* myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select to get more information"
                                                      message:@""
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"a",@"b",@"c", nil];
    myAlert.tag=2;
    [myAlert show];

    //Code comes here immediately, even if I don't select anything on alertView.
    NSLog(@"Does it come here? Yes!");
}
```

My AlertView:

```
if ([alertView tag]==2)
{
    //Some code
    NSString* message = @"Long message";
    if (UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning())
        UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, message);
    else
        NSLog(@"Voice-over is not running.");
}
```

I am also ready to change my code logic. I tried if the code continues after we select a choice on alert view, so that I can make the `message` variable global and post the notification through the `foo` function. It doesn't happen as expected. Program stops after alertView closes.

Does any workaround exist? I am an amateur iOS programmer so a little code along with the explanation would help.

P.S. I can even use something other than alert view, if there is any. I just want to have a pop-up and some buttons as choices.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should create your on Custom popup using `UIView` to display options to the end user. Then first display your popup that gives user the options, once user selected one of them (or tap a button after selecting one of them), call `UIAlertView` to show the relevant messages.

Hope this way your problem will be solved.

Comment: If I create a custom pop-up view, will the execution be stopped? I am thinking of creating a custom pop-up by taking help from [here](http://blog.typpz.com/2013/12/09/ios-sdk-create-a-pop-up-window/). If the execution is going to stop and returns me the button selected by the user, then I don't need an alert view.

Comment: Yes it is custom, so it will proceed only whenever you feel like.